# Apache camel Reactive(Rxjava2)

Tags: apache-camel, rx-java, rx-java2

I am new to Apache camel reactive(Rxjava2).
Looking for one simple "Hello world" observable subscriber example with Apache camel Reactive.
Please help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is is simple example, taken from http://camel.apache.org/rx.html

```
ReactiveCamel rx = new ReactiveCamel(camelContext);
Observable<Message> observable = rx.toObservable("activemq:MyMessages");

observable.subscribe(msg -> {
   // do something
}, err -> {
   System.out.println("failure");
} );
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, do you have a complete example or workable code,  creating ActiveMq connection , setting that in Observable and then consuming it through the subscribed consumer.

Comment: look at for example this: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-camel/apache-camel-activemq-example/